# different ways to define initialState for Redux Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I recently came across this example:

state.d.ts

```
export interface IState {
    token: string | null;
  }
```

```
export const tokenReducer = (
  state: IState['token'] = null,
  { type, payload }: AppAction,
): typeof state => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'LOGIN':
      return payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This works well. However, I tried to change it like this:

```
const initialState: IState = {
  token: null
};

export const tokenReducer = (
  //state: IState['token'] = null,
  state = initialState,
  //state: initialState
  action: AppAction,
): typeof state => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'LOGIN':
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

but I get errors. 
Error on action.payload if I use `state: typeof initialState` or `state = initialState`as per IDE's suggestion:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IState'.ts(2322)
```

If I try `state: initialState`then obviously:

```
'initialState' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof initialState'?ts(2749)
``
What am I doing wrong? Am I making a syntax error or is it just not allowed to define initialStates like this?
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: updated @EmileBergeron

Answer (score 2):

The problem probably is this: You're not returning the state at all. You're just overriding it or returning the token only (not as object), depending on your payload. I suppose that `LOGIN`-action will return a token. So the correct reducer would be as following:

```js
export const tokenReducer = (
  state: IState['token'] = initialState,
  { type, payload }: AppAction,
): IState => {
  switch (type) {
      case 'LOGIN':
        return {
          ...state,
          token: payload,
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

Or does payload contain `{token: string}`?

**Edit:** Aight, after looking carefully at the very first `tokenReducer` I think it reduces the `token` only, not an object. So a correct `initialState` would be:

```js
// this equals the `token` in `IState`
const initialState: string | null = null
```

And yes, assigning `state = initialState,` is syntactically correct.

Comment: This gives me ```Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'IState'.ts(2322)```

Comment: using action.payload instead of action (updated qs)

Comment: I was sloppy looking at `tokenReducer`. Please see my edited post.

Comment: Still gives ```Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'IState'.ts(2322)``` on ```state: IState = initialState,```` and ```Property 'payload' does not exist on type '{ type: "LOGIN"; payload: string; } | { type: "LOGOUT"; }'.ts(2339)````on ```{ type, payload }:```

Comment: of course it is no longer `IState` but the `token` which accepts `string |null`. I've updated the reducer. well yes, then you've to cast `AppAction` explicitly into a `LoginAction` which does contain the payload.